# I Installed the Spyder Notebook plug-in for Spyder with conda install but it didn't work

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

I'm following the instruction from this [link](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/plugins/notebook.html#installing-the-notebook).

`conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide`

I'm using Mac. I want to run JupyterNotebook on Spyder but for some reason, the notebook does not show up on my Spyder app.  I don't even find the plugins file that was supposed to be downloaded to my pc

Comment: What Spyder version  are you using? The spyder-notebook plugin is not yet compatible with Spyder 5 although a PR in its repo is open to do that: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook/issues/360

Comment: Oh, that make sense, year I'm using Spyder 5. I will follow this PR, thank you!